# Spring - Can't load resources (CSS)

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

Well I have been looking for a solution for 2 days all over the net and no matter what I tried nothing worked, than I gonna hope someone here could fix my problem:

I have Spring project which when I load with server and open it up I can't load css file into index.html (yes I don't use jsp):

I will post all my relevant code to be clear:

**index.html** (you can see I tried many paths *_*)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CouponSystem Home Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="couponsystem/resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/couponsystem/resources/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="couponsystem/resources/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>CouponSystem- Home Page</h2>
<hr>

<div class="red-text">Red text</div>
    <br>
    <div class="green-text">Green text</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

**AppConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.orel.couponsystem")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements 
ApplicationContextAware {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine((ISpringTemplateEngine) templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new 
  SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
    }

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

**my project structure:**
[my project structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeGro.jpg)

[image]

**style.css**

```
body{
    background-color:red;
}
.button {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.red-text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.green-text {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!

**UPDATE:**  **ALSO UPDATED AppConfig
my structure:
[structure with index file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxIhg.jpg)

Comment: I think resources defined the way you have should be src/main/resources not src/main/webapp/resources

Comment: show your target structure, and where is your index.html

Comment: Your index html should be in webapp file, i can't see your your index in the project stucture , normally it should work , i did it once , an html page with a spring project, note that i've had also some xhtml pages in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using spring than it is recommended to use `'src/main/resource'`, so please use the artifact `sprint-sample-mvc` to correct it.

Comment: i just updated my structure :(with index.html)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxIhg.jpg    i now used 'src/main/resource' what do you mean by using the artifact sprint-sample-mvc?

Comment: Select the project Archetype `maven-archetype-webapp.`